# How to add an android application into android source code and compile it

Tags: android, rom, custom-rom

Trying to add an application into android source code on ERAGON820 to make it as pre-built app. But getting below error on compiling

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/administrator/ERAGON820_Android-MM-BSP_Relv2.0/source/LA.HB.1.3.2-16800-8x96.0_Relv2.0/out/target/product/msm8996/obj/KERNEL_OBJ'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/administrator/ERAGON820_Android-MM-BSP_Relv2.0/source/LA.HB.1.3.2-16800-8x96.0_Relv2.0/kernel'
mdpath=`find out/target/product/msm8996/system/lib/modules -type f -name modules.dep`; if [ "$mdpath" != "" ];then mpath=`dirname $mdpath`; ko=`find $mpath/kernel -type f -name *.ko`; for i in $ko; do mv $i out/target/product/msm8996/system/lib/modules/; done; fi
mdpath=`find out/target/product/msm8996/system/lib/modules -type f -name modules.dep`; if [ "$mdpath" != "" ];then mpath=`dirname $mdpath`; rm -rf $mpath; fi

#### make failed to build some targets (03:16 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check to make sure mo‌​dules.dep.bin is not empty.
- If you are using Linux try reinstalling linux-image-3.x.x-x-generic 
   something like apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-`uname -r`
   or you can upgrade your kernel.
   If you do not have access to your network then try 
   dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-$(uname -r)

Comment: Thanks for the reply... We are talking about android customization and I don't find any modules.dep.bin within the android source